# How to approach Vertical Sticks challenge?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, probability

This problem is taken from [interviewstreet.com](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4eed18ded76fe)

> Given array of integers Y=y1,...,yn, we have n line segments such that
>   endpoints of segment i are (i, 0) and (i, yi). Imagine that from the
>   top of each segment a horizontal ray is shot to the left, and this ray
>   stops when it touches another segment or it hits the y-axis. We
>   construct an array of n integers, v1, ..., vn, where vi is equal to
>   length of ray shot from the top of segment i. We define V(y1, ..., yn)
>   = v1 + ... + vn.
>
> For example, if we have Y=[3,2,5,3,3,4,1,2], then v1, ..., v8 =
>   [1,1,3,1,1,3,1,2], as shown in the picture below:
>
> [image]
>
> For each permutation p of [1,...,n], we can calculate V(yp1, ...,
>   ypn). If we choose a uniformly random permutation p of [1,...,n], what
>   is the expected value of V(yp1, ..., ypn)?
>
> **Input Format**
>
> First line of input contains a single integer T (1 <= T <= 100). T
>   test cases follow.
>
> First line of each test-case is a single integer N (1 <= N <= 50).
>   Next line contains positive integer numbers y1, ..., yN separated by a
>   single space (0 < yi <= 1000).
>
> **Output Format**
>
> For each test-case output expected value of V(yp1, ..., ypn), rounded
>   to two digits after the decimal point.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 6
> 3
> 1 2 3
> 3
> 3 3 3
> 3
> 2 2 3
> 4
> 10 2 4 4
> 5
> 10 10 10 5 10
> 6
> 1 2 3 4 5 6
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 4.33
> 3.00
> 4.00
> 6.00
> 5.80
> 11.15
> ```
>
> **Explanation**
>
> Case 1: We have V(1,2,3) = 1+2+3 = 6, V(1,3,2) = 1+2+1 = 4, V(2,1,3) =
>   1+1+3 = 5, V(2,3,1) = 1+2+1 = 4, V(3,1,2) = 1+1+2 = 4, V(3,2,1) =
>   1+1+1 = 3. Average of these values is 4.33.
>
> Case 2: No matter what the permutation is, V(yp1, yp2, yp3) = 1+1+1 =
>   3, so the answer is 3.00.
>
> Case 3: V(y1 ,y2 ,y3)=V(y2 ,y1 ,y3) = 5, V(y1, y3, y2)=V(y2, y3, y1) =
>   4, V(y3, y1, y2)=V(y3, y2, y1) = 3, and average of these values is
>   4.00.

A naive solution to the problem will run forever for N=50. I believe that the problem can be solved by independently calculating a value for each stick. I still need to know if there is any other efficient approach for this problem. On what basis do we have to independently calculate value for each stick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly, noted we can solve problem independently for each stick.

Let F(i, len) is number of permutations, that ray from stick i is exactly len.
Then answer is

> (Sum(by i, len) F(i,len)*len)/(n!)

All is left is to count F(i, len). Let a(i) be number of sticks j, that y_j<=y_i. b(i) - number of sticks, that b_j>b_i.

In order to get ray of length len, we need to have situation like this.

```
B, l...l, O  
   len-1 times
```

Where O - is stick #i. B - is stick with bigger length, or beginning. l - is stick with heigth, lesser then ith.

This gives us 2 cases:
1) B is the beginning, this can be achieved in `P(a(i), len-1) * (b(i)+a(i)-(len-1))!` ways.
2) B is bigger stick, this can be achieved in `P(a(i), len-1)*b(i)*(b(i)+a(i)-len)!*(n-len)` ways.

edit: corrected b(i) as 2nd term in (mul)in place of a(i) in case 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please be more clear I'm not able to understand exactly what your logic is.

Comment: We try to count for each stick, how many permuatation are, that ray from it will be exactly len.

Comment: Mebbe i am missing some mathematical backgrnd but could you tell the way to calculate the permutation of individual stick ?

Answer (score 7):

We can solve this problem, by figure out:

> if the *k* th stick is put in *i* th position, what is the expected ray-length of this stick.

then the problem can be solve by adding up all the expected length for all sticks in all positions.

Let `expected[k][i]` be the expected ray-length of *k* th stick put in *i* th position, let `num[k][i][length]` be the number of permutations that *k* th stick put in *i* th position with ray-length equals to `length`, then

> `expected[k][i] = sum( num[k][i][length] * length ) / N!`

How to compute `num[k][i][length]`? For example, for `length=3`, consider the following graph:

> ...GxxxI...

Where `I` is the position, 3 'x' means we need 3 sticks that are strictly lower then `I`, and `G` means we need a stick that are at least as high as `I`.
Let `s_i` be the number of sticks that are smaller then the `k` th the stick, and `g_i` be the number of sticks that are greater or equal to the `k` th stick, then we can choose any one of  `g_i` to put in `G` position, we can choose any `length` of `s_i` to fill the `x` position, so we have:

> `num[k][i][length] =  P(s_i, length) * g_i * P(n-length-1-1)`

In case that all the positions before `I` are all smaller then `I`, we don't need a greater stick in `G`, i.e. `xxxI....`, we have:

> `num[k][i][length] =  P(s_i, length) * P(n-length-1)`

And here's a piece of Python code that can solve this problem:

```
def solve(n, ys):
    ret = 0
    for y_i in ys:
        s_i = len(filter(lambda x: x < y_i, ys))
        g_i = len(filter(lambda x: x >= y_i, ys)) - 1

        for i in range(n):
            for length in range(1, i+1):
                if length == i:
                    t_ret = combination[s_i][length] * factorial[length] * factorial[ n - length - 1 ] 
                else:
                    t_ret = combination[s_i][length] * factorial[length] * g_i * factorial[ n - length - 1 - 1 ]
                ret += t_ret * length

    return ret * 1.0 / factorial[n] + n
```

Comment: why that 'n' is added in the final answer?

Comment: If `n=50` then `factorial[n]` will be very big. This may require big-number data type to implement.

Comment: python's integer is big-number :-)

Comment: @ShusenLiu  I am not able to understand the solution. Is there any simpler version of this problem so that I can increase my understanding bit by bit?

Answer (score 7):

*This is the same question as https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1076/how-to-approach-vertical-sticks-challenge and my answer there (which is a little simpler than those given earlier here) was:*

Imagine a different problem: if you had to place `k` sticks of equal heights in `n` slots then the expected distance between sticks (and the expected distance between the first stick and a notional slot `0`, and the expected distance between the last stick and a notional slot `n+1`) is `(n+1)/(k+1)` since there are `k+1` gaps to fit in a length `n+1`.

Returning to this problem, a particular stick is interested in how many sticks (including itself) as as high or higher.  If this is `k`, then the expected gap before it is also  `(n+1)/(k+1)`.

So the algorithm is simply to find this value for each stick and add up the expectation.  For example, starting with heights of `3,2,5,3,3,4,1,2`, the number of sticks with a greater or equal height is `5,7,1,5,5,2,8,7` so the expectation is `9/6+9/8+9/2+9/6+9/6+9/3+9/9+9/8 = 15.25`.

This is easy to program: for example a single line in R

> ```
> V <- function(Y){(length(Y) + 1) * sum(1 / (rowSums(outer(Y, Y, "<=")) + 1) )}
> ```

gives the values in the [sample output in the original problem](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4eed18ded76fe)

```
> V(c(1,2,3))
[1] 4.333333
> V(c(3,3,3))
[1] 3
> V(c(2,2,3))
[1] 4
> V(c(10,2,4,4))
[1] 6
> V(c(10,10,10,5,10))
[1] 5.8
> V(c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
[1] 11.15
```

Comment: You sir, are a true hero

Comment: but still, won't there be k gaps, instead of k+1?

Comment: If you have `k`sticks then there are `k-1` gaps between the sticks plus a gap before the first stick, plus a gap after the last stick. You may not take account of this last gap in the definition of `V` for a particular case, but it is there and has an impact on the expected value of `V`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't take into account the gap after the last stick. Thank you again :)

Comment: @Henry. I also found this problem recently. But, this time it's solved using your logic. I want to ask you, is it only your logic or researched algorithm? I want to learn too? Sorry, if my question is less polite. Thank you.

Comment: @HusniFirmansyah This was all my own work, but I would not be surprised if whoever asked the original question had thought of something similar